# Tell If A Multi-Word String Contains A Word

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

### Goal:

(The reason I don't think this is a duplicate is that it involves matching the **start** of each word in the string, not just anything in the string)

I'm using Javascript/jQuery. Say I have a sting, which is:

```
Muncie South Gateway Project
```

I'm creating a live search box, which checks the input against the string with each keystroke. I'd like to return a match if the input matches the beginning of a word, not the middle. Example:

```
Mu = Match
Muncie = Match
unc = No Match
cie = No Match
Gatewa = Match
atewa = No Match
```

### What I have

I currently am using this as my check:

```
if (new RegExp(input)).test(string.toLowerCase()) {return '1';}
```

However, this matches all letters including letters in the middle of the word. With it, then my examples get this result:

```
M = Match
Mu = Match
Mun = Match
Muncie = Match
unc = Match // Should not match
cie = Match // Should not match
Gatewa = Match
atewa = Match // Should not match
```

### Question:

I know this can be done by breaking the string apart into separate words and testing each word. But I'm not sure how efficient that would be. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use word boundaries to make sure given input matches only at start of word character:

```
if (new RegExp("\\b" + input)).test(string.toLowerCase()) {return '1';}
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/zN6yG1)

**EDIT:** As per comment below you can use:

```
var re = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + input, "i"));
if (re.test(string)) {return '1';}
```

Comment: I love how simple a change this is. One question though, and it's my fault for not mentioning this specifically in the original question. It seems to treat `@` as the beginning of a new word, so if I had `kelderic@mail.com` then `mail` would trigger it the same as `kelderic` would. Is there a way to make it not treat `@` like a space?

Comment: Is there a better way to change everything to lower case that wouldn't cause those, odedsh?

Comment: Yes that's nice... No need to break it apart. :) +1

Comment: @AndyM: See updated answer for `@` or similar cases.

Comment: Also it would be better to save built regex and reuse it over and over again. See my updated answer for that and also see removal of `toLowerCase` since I use `"i"` for ignore case match now.

Comment: That works perfectly! And thanks for the idea of saving it. I'll have to rebuild it with each keystroke, but at least I can use it through all the loops I'm testing each time.

Comment: Hey, I know that this is a long while later, but I've been using this and noticed that any string starting with `(` doesn't return matching. I see both `(` and `)` in the regex though. I've tried playing around with it and can't get it to recognize that character. Should it be recognizing it already?

Comment: Actually you need to escape `(` and `)` twice in your `input` variable.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! My final REGEX ended up being `(?:^| |@|-)`, which I used along with `.remove('(','')` on both the input and the string, which worked perfectly.  http://regexr.com/39fdg

Answer (score 1):

I would use StartsWith and Contains:

```
// input
instring // the user string 
searchstr //  the string to search

if (searchstr.ToLower().StartsWith(instring.ToLower())
 || searchstr.ToLower().Contains(" "+instring.ToLower()))
{
  // etc
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, it looks like it would work, so +1. I think that I'm going to use anabhava's answer instead though, because it doesn't require as much extra code. Thank you though!

Comment: @AndyM - Sure.  The real question is which is faster -- if you can pre-compile the regex it might be, but normally there is a lot of overhead for regex.

Comment: Good point. There will probably be 10-100 strings to check, so speed will be important as the numbers rise. If it gets laggy, I'll try this out to see if it speeds things up.